# Sequential numbering in Adobe Illustrator in the same artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, illustrator-scripting, numbering, label

I am trying to put numbers from 2001-4000 for labels, I have also created an Excel file with the numbers I need. I haven't found a way to incorporate that file in the textbox.

Comment: Export the excel file as a csv and place the resulting text file in Illustrator?

Comment: Have you looked at variables in Illustrator? This is *exactly* what they are designed to do.